H2 DB executes wrong query while configuring test db for spring boot test
I am writing Junit for one my applications in which I want to use H2 as a test db. So, I have created a test with using @AutoConfigureTestDatabase and used below application-test.yml values
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:spm
    username: spm
    password: 
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

However, on running with this configuration I am getting exception that H2 is getting a syntax error and not able to create the tables.
So, I assumed may some dialect problem would be there and then removed all this config and used
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
Using this I got the same issue. I then switched on the show-sql property and observed the query fired from Hibernate and query fired by H2.
Hibernate query
create table account (
        id bigint not null auto_increment,
        createdBy VARCHAR(128) not null,
        createdTimestamp INT(11) not null,
        modifiedBy VARCHAR(128),
        modifiedTimestamp INT(11),
        description VARCHAR(256),
        name VARCHAR(128) not null,
        status TINYINT(3) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB

H2 Query (coming in stacktrace)
create table account (
id bigint not null auto_increment, 
createdBy VARCHAR(128) not null, 
createdTimestamp INT[*](11) not null, 
modifiedBy VARCHAR(128), 
modifiedTimestamp INT(11), 
description VARCHAR(256), 
name VARCHAR(128) not null, 
status TINYINT(3) not null, 
primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB

I noticed that createdTimestamp is not having proper format. However, hibernate is firing correct query and it working fine in my production profile with MySQL.
The createdTimestamp along with modifiedTimestamp comes from a base entity which is a mappedSuperclass.
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

   @Column(name = "createdTimestamp", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
   @JsonProperty("createdTimestamp")
   protected Long createdTimestamp;

   @Column(name = "modifiedTimestamp", columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
   @JsonProperty("modifiedTimestamp")
   protected Long modifiedTimestamp;
}

Could someone please help here why H2 is modifying the query in such way and what is the solution?

You must enable MySQL compatibility mode of H2 to use MySQL-specific features such as INT(11) or engine=InnoDB.
